# Vim: "brace matching" for languages without braces? (Ruby, Python, etc)

Tags: vim, ruby

Vim is great at highlighting matching braces. But lately I'm working in Ruby, where method definitions generally start with `do` and end with `end` instead of `{` and `}`. Similarly, `if` statements and `case` statements and others don't use braces, just keywords.

Does anybody have a configuration which can highlight matching keywords like this - for instance, when I'm on an `end`, highlight the `do` that started that block?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413189/vim-highlight-keyword-pairs-in-ruby-def-end-do-end-etc

Answer (score 2):

Try [ruby matchit](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=290) or [python matchit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=386).